# How to d3.csv import data from severals files?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I build from differents csv files (each contains only two rows : column names and associated values) the `outData` tab in this way :

```
var outData = new Array();
for(s in sources){
    d3.csv(sources[s], function(error, data) {
        outData.push({'value' : +data[0]['var']});
    });
}
```

A `console.log(outData)` instruction give me what I expect :

```
[Object, Object]
```

and for each Object, a good expected format, such as `{value:36}`

The problem is that all *d3* functions don't seem to work on that tab.

For example, a `d3.max(outData, function(d){return d.value;})` return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your other code...

`d3.csv()` function are asynchronous and code after `for(s in sources){` starts before `outData` array is filled up. That's why you see it as `undefined` and as valid inside `d3.csv()` accessor functions. You have to use `outData` only when all files are read. One possible solution:

```
var outData = [];
var counter = 0;

for (s in sources){
    d3.csv(sources[s], function(error, data) {
        counter++;
        outData.push({
            'value' : +data[0]['var']
        });

        if (counter == sources.length) {
            console.log(outData);
            restOfCode();
        }
    });
}

function restOfCode() {
    console.log('restOfCode outData:');
    console.log(outData);
}
```

Comment: The asynchronous behaviour of d3.csv was the problem.